# Prevent unkonwn sender in Postfix

Tags: linux, ubuntu, postfix

I am struggling to prevent SPAM generated from my server.

my mail.log reads like this:

```
<postmaster@mywebsolutions.co.in> from p57bfa587.dip0.t-
ipconnect.de[87.191.165.135]; from=<postmaster@mywebsolutions.c
o.in> to=<2709457912@txt.att.net> proto=ESMTP helo=<p57bfa587.dip0.t-
ipconnect.de>
```

mywebsolutions.co.in is my domain. but `p57bfa587.dip0.t-
    ipconnect.de` is not neither `2709457912@txt.att.net`

Now I want to block any unknown sender. but couldn't find anyway to prevent this.

I have also added in my postfix main.cf

`smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender = Yes`

Also
`smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unlisted_sender`

Full Block reads like this:
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unlisted_sender, check_sender_access regexp:/etc/postfix/tag_as_originating.re , permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, check_sender_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_sender.cf, check_sender_access regexp:/etc/postfix/tag_as_foreign.re
smtpd_client_restrictions = check_client_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_client.cf

What rule I should change or update to prevent SPAM Originating from my server.

Comment: You have much larger issue, sorry to say this. If your server is generating SPAM, it means it is **compromised**. https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server

Comment: Additionally take a look at this http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#authorized_submit_users in order to immediately stop web server user (`apache2` or `www-data`) to send spam.